# What to do about my internship?

Tags: software-industry, internship

I am currently doing an internship in a busy company as a programmer. The thing is I've interned at this company in the past, and they liked me (last year, my degree has 2 internships) and asked me to stay in the end as a job.

This year even though they keep saying they want me they haven't yet assigned me with a task, plus they placed me in web developing (against what they promised me previously) which something I really can't see myself doing.

The company has a really bad reputation for being too strict and with a really toxic environment but a job is a job.  Still, I fear i might be thrown to web development and that is something that would make me hate my job.

I do love programming above everything else and I love challenges and "being thrown to the wolves" but web development is something I've tasted in the past and I know I don't enjoy the flavor, what could i do?

Comment: I had to go to web development 2 jobs ago (and my degree specialization is Apps Dev). I've gotten used to it, as it's coding under a different cowl, but I certainly know the feels. I'd be more worried about the toxicity of the work environment. You could be doing systems development in assembly and loving it, but if you have a bad work environment it would feel like working on the newest web project and you'd end up hating it as well.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yeah, but this company is not only web focused, and my issue is that getting a job with a professional degree may not be easy (I assume).

Comment: @JoeStrazzere no, never did I claimed that, still here is close to impossible to get a job in the area with professional degree, It is not that i am chasing an easy solution, but none of my colleges who finished the degree and  didn't stayed in the company they internship at are employed in the area...

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Not really the point of the question, plus I do feel it doesn't add anything as it is not an option. Still question is already answered with a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Discuss with your current employer what types of positions are available for a permanent employee.  The types of projects and assignments are usually different for interns rather than permanent employees.  When I was an IT intern I actually had to interview for permanent positions so I was able to discuss with the managers what the job entailed and if it was something that sounded interesting to me.
2. Write up a resume and apply for positions you want if the current company doesn't have a position you're interested in.  Never get blinded into staying with a company just because it's easier.  The more companies that are interested in you and your skills can only benefit you and give you more leverage for negotiating a salary.

Also, talk to your manager or supervisor about why you're in web development instead of the position you were more interested in.  Maybe the company lost a couple employees from the web team and desperately needed help.  The fact that you're willing to do other types of work is great for a resume plus it shows that you're willing to help out the company.

Comment: That is the think manager only spoke once with me this year. I am stressing so bad... But thanks, makes sense your answer.

Comment: Communication is the best tool you have.  If the company doesn't know what your professional goals are, then they will make assumptions.  If you're doing web dev and doing good work they will assume that's maybe what you want to do.

Don't assume you HAVE to stay with the company just because your internship was there.  Sometimes it's easier because you know the people and products, but it limits your negotiation leverage

Comment: It is a professional degree (something we have in Europe) and in my country people look down on them so i know that if i don't stay here where they already know i have some skill i am afraid i won't find another place that would want me.

Comment: The benefit you have though is that you're already in a company with a position. It will never hurt to update your resume and apply for other positions.  The worst thing that will happen is that they say, "no" and then you stay where you're already at.